Child component not updating data
I have a child component Table.
Table.php
<?php

namespace App\UI\Http\Twig\Components\Molecules;

use Symfony\UX\LiveComponent\Attribute\AsLiveComponent;
use Symfony\UX\LiveComponent\Attribute\LiveProp;
use Symfony\UX\LiveComponent\DefaultActionTrait;

#[AsLiveComponent]
final class Table
{
    use DefaultActionTrait;

    #[LiveProp] public array $headers = [];
    #[LiveProp(updateFromParent: true, onUpdated: 'onDataUpdate')] public array $data = [];

    public function onDataUpdate(): void
    {
        $this->data;
    }
}

<div {{ attributes }}>

    {% if data|length > 0 %}
        <div class="table">
            <div class="row header">
                {% for header in headers %}
                    <div class="cell">{{ header }}</div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>

            {% for row in data %}
                <div class="row">
                    {% for cell in row %}
                        <div class="cell">{{ cell }}</div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% else %}
        <span class="no-data">Er is momenteel nog geen data beschikbaar.</span>
    {% endif %}

</div>


This component is loaded from my parent component like this:
<twig:Molecules:Table :headers="childrenTableHeaders" :data="data" data-live-id="{{ 'childrentable' ~ childrenTableData|length }}" />

This is my parent component:
<?php

namespace App\UI\Http\Twig\Components\Pages\Admin;

use App\Domain\Service\User\ChildServiceInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Attribute\AsEventListener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\UX\LiveComponent\Attribute\AsLiveComponent;
use Symfony\UX\LiveComponent\Attribute\LiveAction;
use Symfony\UX\LiveComponent\Attribute\LiveListener;
use Symfony\UX\LiveComponent\Attribute\LiveProp;
use Symfony\UX\LiveComponent\ComponentToolsTrait;
use Symfony\UX\LiveComponent\DefaultActionTrait;

#[AsLiveComponent]
final class AdminImportChildren
{
    use DefaultActionTrait;
    use ComponentToolsTrait;

    public function __construct(
        private RequestStack $requestStack,
        private readonly ChildServiceInterface $childService,
        private LoggerInterface $logger,
    )
    {
    
    }
    
    #[LiveProp] public bool $showAdminImportChildrenForm = false;
    #[LiveProp] public array $childrenTableHeaders = ['Voornaam', 'Achternaam', 'Geboortedatum', 'BSN'];
    #[LiveProp] public array $childrenTableData = [];

    public function mount(): void
    {
        $this->refreshChildrenTableData();
    }

    #[AsEventListener('import.children')]
    public function refreshChildrenTableData(): void
    {
        $this->logger->info('Refreshing children table data');
        $allChildren = $this->childService->getAllChildren();
        $this->childrenTableData = array_map(function($child) {
            return [
                'voornaam' => $child->getFirstName(),
                'achternaam' => $child->getLastName(),
                'geboortedatum' => $child->getBirthDate()->format('d-m-Y'),
                'bsn' => $child->getSsn(),
            ];
        }, $allChildren);
    }

    #[LiveAction]
    public function toggleAdminImportChildrenForm(): void
    {
        $this->showAdminImportChildrenForm = !$this->showAdminImportChildrenForm;
    }
    
    #[LiveListener('closeAdminImportChildrenFormEvent')]
    public function closeAdminImportChildrenForm(): void
    {
        $this->showAdminImportChildrenForm = false;
    }
}


When data is loaded in, I want to rerender the Table component with the new data. I am sure #[AsEventListener('import.children')] is triggered because I get the log-message.
But for some reason Table is not showing the new data?

Following a comment by the original poster, rewritten answer:
#[AsEventListener] is designed to work with the Symfony Event system. It cannot substitute a #[LiveListener] (in the context of a LiveComponent).
As you indicate, the log is indeed being triggered. A #[AsEventListener] decorated method is just a listener to a regular Symfony event. It’s triggered server-side. This does not produce a LiveComponent JSON "patch" response, nor does it inform the frontend to fetch new data.
Without a #[LiveListener] or a Live action invocatiion, there’s no built in mechanism to push these changes to the frontend. Thats why you see logs (proof the event fired) but no changes in your frontend UI.
This is where something like Mercure can prove to be a useful tool. But there's a number of other options, although I'm not sure where you're actually dispatching this event.

If it's dispatched in a different component, substitute it with an emit: UX Live Component Emit
You could use Turbo Streams and use that to display the updated data, in conjunction with your Live Component
If the user is responsible for the data changing you could use Stimulus (or vanilla JS) and have it dispatch an event that your LiveComponent listens to, although it's probably not applicable in your case.

Additionally, you are passing :data="data" from parent to child component. This is simply passing a "data" string rather than the actual data.

LiveListener only works for events emitted in LiveComponents using $this->emit. And the AsEventListener works fine as mentioned in my post.

That's quite surprising as the #[AsEventListener] is in no way able to re-render the component. I will set up a small test and see if I can reproduce.

Sorry just re-read your question, missed the part on the log triggering but not the re-render, I have updated my answer
